# Complexity of Graph Traversal

Tags: graph, time-complexity, traversal

What is the computational complexity of breadth-first and depth-first traversal in terms of the number of vertices v and the number of edges e when the graph is represented as an adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is `O(v^2)`, as the adjacency matrix must be searched to obtain all neighbors of a single vertex.